# MySQL => Postgres migration: How do I script the sequence start values?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, sequence, database-administration

I'm migrating from MySQL to Postgres with `mysqldump` and `psql`. I copied all the data but the `serial`s start at 1. I need to update the starting value to the last id number. How can I script this to do it automatically? I tried

```
alter sequence keyword_id_seq restart (select max(id) from keyword);
```

It gave an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(" at character 39
STATEMENT:  alter sequence keyword_id_seq restart (select max(id) from keyword);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: alter sequence keyword_id_seq restart (select max(id) from k...
```

I can't set the start value when creating the sequence (with `CREATE SEQUENCE table_colname_seq START 123;`) because new values may be inserted into the old DB while I'm editing the file or before the data is copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setval`.

```
SELECT setval('keyword_id_seq', (select max(id) from keyword));
```